# Using Amazon services to query products on the amazon website

Tags: web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm creating a application where the user will type in the name of a video game and a query will be sent to a servlet. I want this query to search the amazon product database and if the game is found i want to grab the information such as the name, publisher, platform genre etc and add this information to my database. Just like price grabber does. There is an example below.

http://video-games.pricegrabber.co.uk/nintendo-ds-games/m/25813985/details/st=product_tab/

Can this be done and if so what will i need to know and learn to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) to query for this kind of product information. However the current [Terms of Use](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html) appear to restrict you from storing the data into your database for more than 24 hours.